# Quicksort - recursive

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I am trying to code quicksort in two ways, one in-place, and the other by using separate arrays. I'm kind of stuck on some of the logic, take a look at what I have, Thanks for the help in advance!

```
public List<Integer> sort(List<Integer> arr){
  if(arr.length > 0)
    List<Integer> ret = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  ret = quickSort(arr);
  return ret;
 }

public List<Integer> quickSort(List<Integer> arr){
  if(arr.length < 2)
    return;

  int pivot = arr[0];
  List<Integer> left = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  List<Integer> right = new ArrayList<Integer>();

  for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i] <= pivot)
      left.add(arr[i]);
    else
      right.add(arr[i]);
  }
  quickSort(left);
  quickSort(right);

}
```

Now i'm stuck, I don't know what I would do after recursively going through both sets, mostly stuck on how would I connect them together and return a sorted list.

Comment: Put left and right together and return it?

Comment: is my implementation correct though?

Comment: Why dont you test if your result is correct? Input an array and look yourself if the result is sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine `left` and `right` sequences together. You need to do it at the end of your algorithm (before the closing `}`). In pseudo code:

```
int leftpos = 0, rightpos = 0;
List newlist = new ArrayList();
for(int pos = 0; pos < arr.length; pos++)
  if left[pos] < right[pos] newlist.add(left[leftpos++]);
    else newlist.add(right[rightpos++]);
return newlist;
```

This is just a pseudo-code. You need to add code to check lengths of each array (`left` and `right`) in the for cycle.

Also I must note that this is far from quicksort. So many `new` array allocations make the algorithm extremely slow and that's unwelcome when sorting.

Also, right side of line 3 is redundant. You don't need to allocate anything here, as it is overwritten in the next line. I would just simply replace your lines 3-5 with this:

```
return quickSort(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me have a crack at this for you.

First off, you always want to do in-place sorting unless you're working with *linked* lists (and even then it usually pays to convert to an array, sort in place, then convert back to a linked list -- it puts way less pressure on the garbage collector).  .NET List<>s are actually expanding arrays.

Next, quicksort is really all about the pivot operation.  Here's one way to do it:

```
// Quicksort the sub-array xs[lo..hi].
void QSort(int[] xs, int lo, int hi) {
    if (hi <= lo) return; // Don't sort empty or singleton sub-arrays.
    var p = [choose some pivot value from xs[lo..hi]];
    var a = lo; // Invariant: x[lo..a - 1] <= p.
    var z = hi; // Invariant: p < x[z + 1..hi].
    while (a <= z) {
        if (xs[a] <= p) a++; else Swap(xs, a, z--);
    }
    QSort(xs, lo, a - 1); // Sort the items <= p.
    QSort(xs, z + 1, hi); // Sort the items > p.
}

void Swap(int[] xs, int i, int j) {
    var tmp = xs[i];
    xs[i] = xs[j];
    xs[j] = tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple implementation on Groovy

```
def qs(list) {
  if (list.size() < 2) return list   
  def pivot = list[0]
  def items = list.groupBy { it <=> pivot }.withDefault { [] }
  qs(items[-1]) + items[0] + qs(items[1])
}
```