# Java quickSortRecursive on List

Tags: java, algorithm, oop, quicksort, insertion-sort

I'm trying to get my `quickSortRecursive` method to work, but it isn't passing my test cases. Note that I'm sorting by zipcode:

```java
public class Location implements Comparable<Location> {

    private final String zipCode;
    private final String city;
    private final Double latitude;
    private final Double longitude;
    private final String state;

    public Location(String zipCode, Double latitude, Double longitude, String city, String state) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
        this.city = city;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return this.city;
    }

    public String getZipCode() {
        return this.zipCode;
    }

    public Double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public Double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }
    

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Location o) {
        int result = 0;
        if(Integer.parseInt(this.zipCode) > Integer.parseInt(o.getZipCode())) {
            result = -1;
        }
    
        if(Integer.parseInt(this.zipCode) < Integer.parseInt(o.getZipCode())) {
            result = 1;
        }
        
        return result;
    }
```

This is my `Location` class followed by my `compareTo` method.

There is also my `quickSort` method that isn't working.
I have an `insertionSort` method that works perfectly fine.

```java
public static void quickSortRecursive(List<Location> list, int from, int to) {
        if (from < to) {
            int pivot = from;
            int left = from + 1;
            int right = to;
            Location pivotValue = list.get(pivot);
            while (left <= right) {
                while (left <= to && pivotValue.compareTo(pivotValue) < left) {
                    left++;
                }
                while (right > from && pivotValue.compareTo(pivotValue) > right) {
                    right--;
                }
                if (left < right) {
                    Collections.swap(list, left, right);
                }
            }
            Collections.swap(list, pivot, left - 1);
            quickSortRecursive(list, from, right - 1); 
            quickSortRecursive(list, right + 1, to);  
        }
    }

public static void quickSort(List<Location> locations) {
        quickSortRecursive(locations, 0, locations.size() - 1);
    }


    public static  void insertionSort(List<Location> locations) {
          for (int j = 1; j < locations.size(); j++) {
              Location current = locations.get(j);
                int i = j-1;
                while ((i > -1) && ((locations.get(i).compareTo(current)) == 1)) {
                    locations.set(i+1, locations.get(i));
                    i--;
                }
                locations.set(i+1, current);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Quicksort - recursive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13597030/quicksort-recursive)

Answer (score 0):

This should fix the quick sort issue.

```
    public void quick_sort(List<Location> locations) {
        quick_sort(locations, 0, locations.size() - 1);
    }

    private void quick_sort(List<Location> locations, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
        if (startIndex > endIndex) {
            return;
        }
        int pivotIndex = partition(locations, startIndex, endIndex);
        quick_sort(locations, startIndex, pivotIndex - 1);
        quick_sort(locations, pivotIndex + 1, endIndex);
    }

    private int partition(List<Location> locations, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
        int smallerIndex = startIndex;
        for (int biggerIndex = startIndex + 1; biggerIndex <= endIndex; biggerIndex++) {
            if (locations.get(startIndex).compareTo(locations.get(biggerIndex)) == -1) {
                smallerIndex++;
                swapElements(locations, smallerIndex, biggerIndex);
            }
        }
        swapElements(locations, startIndex, smallerIndex);
        return smallerIndex;
    }


    private void swapElements(List<Location> input, int firstIndex, int secondIndex) {
        Location temp = input.get(firstIndex);
        input.set(firstIndex, input.get(secondIndex));
        input.set(secondIndex, temp);
    }
```